# JFrame is blank

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

any ideas what im doing wrong here..im supposed to see 2 rectangles in my JFrame but all i get is a grey box. So no rectangles, colors or nothing responds to my code.

Here is the class with the main method :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Paron {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      JFrame f = new JFrame("Rektanglar");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Rektanglar r = new Rektanglar ();
      f.add(r);
     f.setSize(400, 250);
      f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and here is my JPanel code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rektanglar extends JPanel {

    public void PaintComponent (Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent (g);
       this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

       g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g.fillRect(25,25, 100, 100);
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.fillRect(40,40,100,100);

    }
}
```

what am i missing? thanks for any help

Comment: Always annotate with @Override a method that is supposed to override another one. The compiler will then catch those kinds of mistakes. And of course, a method that does not respect the Java naming conventions has 0 chance of overriding a standard method. Learn and respect these conventions.

Comment: @Zenith That's actually a different issue where a blank `JFrame` is being used. This relates to a typo in the `JPanel` used.

Comment: @Reimeus Fair enough. I can't change the reason, however if I could I'd close anyway as typo-questions need to be, according to Meta.

Answer (score 5):

It's [`paintComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) not `PaintComponent`. Java is case sensitive.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

Add the `@Override` annotation to allow the compiler to check for the existence of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void PaintComponent (Graphics g) {
```

the `p` for `PaintComponent` has to be lowercase:

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
```